# How to filter and select different columns in Pandas to generate a specific output

Tags: pandas

I have below code:

```py
import pandas as pd
def EMP1():
    df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['EMP', 'name1', 'Boston', 'M'],
    ['EMP', 'name2', 'korea', 'F'],
    ['MGR', 'name3', 'North America','M'],
    ['MGR', 'name4', 'AUSIES', 'F']
    ],
    columns=("DESIG", "NAMES", "CITIES", "GENDER"))
    spl = df[df.GENDER=='M']
    print(spl)
EMP1()
```

what am trying is to generate one print output like:

Details of employees names list `<NAMES of EACH DESIG>` reporting for desig list `<DESIG details>` are gender list `<Gender details>`.

EG: Details of employees name1 reporting to EMP are gender M
    Details of employees name3 reporting to MGR are gender M

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc`

**Ex:**

```
def EMP1():
    df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['EMP', 'name1', 'Boston', 'M'],
    ['EMP', 'name2', 'korea', 'F'],
    ['MGR', 'name3', 'North America','M'],
    ['MGR', 'name4', 'AUSIES', 'F']
    ],
    columns=("DESIG", "NAMES", "CITIES", "GENDER"))
    spl = df.loc[df.GENDER=='M', ["DESIG", "NAMES", "GENDER"]]
    print(spl)
EMP1()
```

**Output:**

```
  DESIG  NAMES GENDER
0   EMP  name1      M
2   MGR  name3      M
```

Comment: how to print that in below format:    Details of employees names list <list of names> reporting for DESIG list <list of design> are gender list <M>.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use:

```
df[['DESIG','NAMES','GENDER']].T.to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['EMP', 'EMP', 'MGR', 'MGR'],
 ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'],
 ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F']]
```

OR for just spl:

```
spl[['DESIG','NAMES','GENDER']].T.to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['EMP', 'MGR'], ['name1', 'name3'], ['M', 'M']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def EMP1():
    df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['EMP', 'name1', 'Boston', 'M'],
    ['EMP', 'name2', 'korea', 'F'],
    ['MGR', 'name3', 'North America','M'],
    ['MGR', 'name4', 'AUSIES', 'F']
    ],
    columns=("DESIG", "NAMES", "CITIES", "GENDER"))
    spl = df[df.GENDER=='M']
    print(df)
    for x in df.index:
        print('Details of employees names list ' + df.loc[x,'NAMES'] + 'reporting '
            ' for desig list ' +   df.loc[x,'DESIG'] + ' are gender list ' +  df.loc[x,'GENDER'])
EMP1()
```

Maybe this? I dont know if there are any difference but I am using the newest edition of pandas